# How can I pass a list as an index set for product

Tags: function-construction

I want to evaluate a Blaschke product based on the set of zeroes, and compute its preimage for some points.

The Blaschke Product looks like:

$$B(z) = z^n\prod_{a_k\in \text{zeroes}} \frac{z - a_k}{1 - \bar{a_k}z} $$

where the set zeroes is a set of numbers where the Blaschke Product is designated to vanish.

The code I wrote looks like

```
BP [z_, zeroes_List] = Product[z^Boole[a == 0], {a, zeroes}] * 
Product[((z - a)/(1 - a\[Conjugate]*z))^Boole[a != 0], {a, zeroes}]
```

but for some reason Mathematica evaluates this function as something completely different. So I don't know how to proceed.

I do have other code that works in evaluating some input, but Mathematica couldn't find the preimages of it, so this is also undesirable. It looks like this:

```
BP := {z, zeroes} |-> Product[z^Boole[a == 0], {a, zeroes}] * 
Product[((z - a)/(1 - a\[Conjugate]*z))^Boole[a != 0], {a, zeroes}]
```

I'm completely new to the language, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! Here are some notes about function definition. It's all about when expressions get evaluated. When using `=`, the right hand side is evaluated first, and then the left hand side is set to it. Be careful: named patterns on the left hand side, like `z_` and `zeroes_List`, aren't bound, as you can see from the syntax highlighting (they'll appear in blue or black). So if you have another definition for those symbols somewhere, it could mess up your intended code! consider `x = 4; f[x_] = x + 1`. This will always evaluate to `5`, no matter the input.

Comment: In general, it's typical to define functions with `:=`, or `SetDelayed`, which does not evaluate the right hand side until the function is called and the patterns are replaced. Unlike `=`, it does bind its patterns, so `x = 4; f[x_] := x + 1` will behave nicely, and e.g. `f[9]` will give `10`. (Sometimes you will want to force the right hand side to evaluate first; this is not one of those times. For that, you could use `Block[{x}, f[x_] = x + 1]`, effectively temporarily clearing `x` for the duration of the definition, without fear.)

Comment: The issue is premature evaluation, as mentioned by @thorimur. Since the right side of your definition is evaluated before `zeroes` has a value, `Product` interprets `{a, zeroes}` as `{a, 1, zeroes}`, i.e. "the product with a going from `1` to `zeroes`". The second example works, because `Function` (`|->`) always prevents evaluation of the right side until arguments are given.

Comment: Now, note that the syntax `BP := {z, zeroes} |-> ...` is highly nonstandard. Why? Because functions (defined with `|->`, `Function`, or `&`) don't evaluate their bodies (right hand sides) anyway until called. But neither does `:=`, so you're avoiding evaluation twice! So, you could use `BP = {z, zeroes}, |-> ...` to the same effect. At that point, though, you may as well simply use `BP[z_, zeroes_List] := ...`, as you get all the benefits of pattern-matching (like constraining `zeroes` to be a list) that `|->` leaves you without.

Comment: Also: while your `Boole` solution is very nice, you might also find something like `Piecewise[{{z, a == 0}, {<...>, a != 0}}]` useful! :)

Comment: ok, so, now that all the technical stuff is out of the way: I'm not quite sure what you mean by preimages here. Can you give an example of the input/output you would like to receive? E.g. do you have a fixed set of `zeroes`? (are they numerical or symbolic?) and, just additional details in general would be useful! :)

Comment: (I'm going to sleep now, but in case it's useful to you: if you have explicit zeroes and preimage points (and a working function!), you might find something with `Solve` helpful, e.g. `sol = Solve[5 == BP[z, {1, 2, 3}], z]`. You can use the results of `Solve` here (since we're solving for `z`) with `z /. sol`, which will thread over the list of rule lists and give you a list of the two solutions. Not sure if this is what you were already doing, though.)

Comment: @thorimur thanks so much for your help!! yep it unfortunately was a typo :(. But it is also nice to know how to construct piecewise function.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `=`, Mathematica evaluates the right hand side of your equation first - then sets the left hand side equal to that. So

```
BP[z_, zeroes_List] = Product[z^Boole[a == 0], {a, zeroes}] * Product[((z - a)/(1 - a\[Conjugate]*z))^Boole[a != 0], {a, zeroes}]
```

First calculates

```
Product[z^Boole[a == 0], {a, zeroes}] * Product[((z - a)/(1 - a\[Conjugate]*z))^Boole[a != 0], {a, zeroes}]
```

which gives a Piecewise

```
\[Piecewise]    -1  zeroes==1
(z^-zeroes Pochhammer[1-z,zeroes])/Pochhammer[(-1+z)/z,zeroes]  True
```

and then sets `BP` equal to that. You instead want to use the `:=` which is `SetDelayed` and waits until you give `BP` the arguments `z` and `zeros` before evaluating the right hand side. This way the product will be done only once the list of zeros is provided. **So what you want to do is**

```
BP[z_, zeroes_List] := Product[z^Boole[a == 0], {a, zeroes}] * Product[((z - a)/(1 - a\[Conjugate]*z))^Boole[a != 0], {a, zeroes}]
```